# convert a text buffer to a pdf file?

Tags: pdf

How can we convert the current text buffer to a pdf file, preferably turning those headings started with * into bookmarks of the pdf file. 
For example, turning the Emacs integrated tutorial (shown by C-h t) into a bookmarked pdf file. Thanks.

Comment: Look at [exporting from `org-mode` to LaTeX/PDF](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-and-PDF-export.html).

Comment: specifically `org-latex-export-to-pdf`

Comment: Just for the sake of diversity: you can do `C-u M-x ps-print-buffer` and then convert the resulting PostScript file to PDF (if your files aren't Org files and you just want to have plain text kind of PDF). Similarly, `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` is what it sounds like.

Comment: @PythonNut: `C-c C-e is undefined`

Comment: @casey: the command is not found

Comment: @Tim try doing `M-x` `org-mode`.

Comment: @PythonNut: Thanks. your link says `C-c C-e l p`, but when I hit `l`, it says `Need a file name to be able to export`

Answer (score 18):

You can put the below in your `init.el` and bind the function to a binding of your choice.

The function prints the file in current buffer as a PDF in the same folder by default.

Here the function requires the binary `ps2pdf` for converting `.ps` to `.pdf`. But you can replace that with any available pdf generator on your system.

```el
(require 'ps-print)
(when (executable-find "ps2pdf")
  (defun modi/pdf-print-buffer-with-faces (&optional filename)
    "Print file in the current buffer as pdf, including font, color, and
underline information.  This command works only if you are using a window system,
so it has a way to determine color values.

C-u COMMAND prompts user where to save the Postscript file (which is then
converted to PDF at the same location."
    (interactive (list (if current-prefix-arg
                           (ps-print-preprint 4)
                         (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))
                                 ".ps"))))
    (ps-print-with-faces (point-min) (point-max) filename)
    (shell-command (concat "ps2pdf " filename))
    (delete-file filename)
    (message "Deleted %s" filename)
    (message "Wrote %s" (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename) ".pdf"))))
```

Comment: I was wondering what the `modi/` does in the function name, but that's your last name to indicate your personal functions?

Answer (score 6):

This does not address the specific issue of bookmarks in the PDF, but does address the general problem of converting buffers to PDF.

If you want to get a PDF "screenshot" of the buffer **as you actually see it** -- not showing hidden text -- then a good alternative is to [htmlize](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) the buffer, and convert the result from HTML to PDF.  You could use this, for example, to build a PDF version of your Org Agenda.  (Note that the `ps-print`-based answer from Kaushal Modi would **show** hidden buffer contents.)

## recipe

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `htmlize-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>, <kbd>C-x C-w</kbd> `buf.html` <kbd>RET</kbd>; then run on the command line:

`pandoc --from=html --to=latex --variable geometry="landscape" -o buf.pdf buf.html`

## example (screenshot)

[image]

## See also

There is an interesting discussion about "vector screenshots" here:
[Can I take vector (SVG) screenshots of Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19123/can-i-take-vector-svg-screenshots-of-emacs) (what I have described could be seen as a *very* limited example of a "vector screenshot".)

Answer (score 5):

You can do `C-u M-x ps-print-buffer` to print current buffer to a PS file and then pipe it through `ps2pdf`.

Comment: I often forget that I need the `C-u` prefix argument.